# Enable Excel PHP PDO driver in Ubuntu Linux 12

Tags: php, ubuntu, pdo

This line of code `new PDO (" odbc: Driver = {Microsoft Excel Driver (*. Xls, *. Xlsx, *. Xlsm, *. Xlsb)}; DBQ =` works fine if my web server is on Windows, but Ubuntu is not true, I can not find how to install the PDO driver for Excel in PHP 5.

Thanks for taking the time on this question.

Comment: Ok...you have some suggestion for my case? tank's

Comment: tanks Roman Newaza; I use Lunux Ubuntu 12.04, but I want reused a fragment of code with pdo_excel that is the reason; reuse.
I want know if in PHP has a PDO Driver for Libre Office.

Comment: Check with PDO Drivers page: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php

Comment: You could also try to use PHPExcel instead

Answer (score 2):

PHP can manipulate COM objects.

Only in Windows plataform you can do things like:

```
<?php
$word = new COM("C:\docs\word.doc");
?>
```

This will create a new instance if there is no running instance available or it will return a handle to the running instance, if available. That's because Windows have ODBC driver working with COM resources.

In your case try use http://www.unixodbc.org/ in Linux, Excel driver are support by this project by http://www.easysoft.com.

[image: RMS ODBC Driver]

The bad news are RMS driver from EasySoft it's not free :(

Comment: will try to review this proposal, I appreciate your response and my excuse delay contestasion.